# Professional Groups and Associations

Tags: untagged

After reading [How valuable do you find professional memberships?](https://serverfault.com/questions/17423/how-valuable-do-you-find-professional-memberships) I thought it would be useful to list the various professional groups and associations available.

Discussion of the value (or not) of the groups belongs with the [How valuable do you find professional memberships?](https://serverfault.com/questions/17423/how-valuable-do-you-find-professional-memberships) question.

---

***System Administration Specific***

**Global**

[PASS](http://www.sqlpass.org/), Professional Association for SQL Server

**Australia**

[SAGE-AU](http://www.sage-au.org.au), The System Administrators Guild of Australia

**Germany**

[sage@guug](http://www.guug.de/sage/), System Administration Special Interest Group within the German Unix User Group

**Ireland**

[The Systems Administrators' Guild of Ireland](http://sysadmin.ie/), The Systems Administrators' Guild of Ireland

[SAGE-IE](http://www.sage-ie.org/), The Systems Administrators' Guild of Ireland

(Two groups with the same name and different web sites?)

**USA**

[LOPSA](http://www.lopsa.org), The League of Professional System Administrators

[NPA](http://www.npanet.org/), Network Professional Association

[SAGE](http://www.sage.org), The [USENIX](http://www.usenix.org/) Special Interest Group for Sysadmins

*Regional*

[NC*SA](http://www.ncsysadmin.org/), North Carolina System Administrators

---

***IT And Computing in General***

**Global**

[ACM](http://www.acm.org), Association for Computing Machinery

[IEEE Computer Society](http://www.computer.org/), The IEEE Computer Society

**Australia**

[ACS](http://acs.org.au), Australian Computer Society

**Canada**

[CIPS](http://www.cips.ca/about), Canadian Information Processing Society

**UK**

[BCS](http://www.bcs.org.uk), British Computer Society

[UKUUG](http://ukuug.org/), the UK's Unix & Open Systems User Group

**USA**

[USENIX](http://www.usenix.org/), The Advanced Computing Systems Association

---

Please add any more that you know of.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't on topic anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for an organization that has an active local chapter.  Even large groups like ACM and IEEE Computer Society will be of limited benefit unless you are active.  I have found that local chapters make the benefits much greater and offer more opportunities to get involved.  That is unless someone is only looking at something to put on a resume.

Answer (score 1):

**Worldwide**

[PASS](http://www.sqlpass.org/) - Professional Association for SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

**Worldwide**

[IEEE Computer Society](http://www.computer.org)

**Canada**

[CIPS](http://www.cips.ca/about) - Canadian Information Processing Society

Answer (score 1):

[UKUUG](http://ukuug.org/), the UK's Unix & Open Systems User Group. They organise a twice yearly conference, training days and seminars, and actively promote and debate open standards with governmental bodies in the UK and EU.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note:  LOPSA is not just USA-based.  We have members world-wide.

Answer (score 0):

Worldwide:

[SANS Institute](http://sans.org) (**S**ysAdmin, **A**udit, **N**etworking, and **S**ecurity)

Answer (score 0):

Worldwide:

[LPI (Linux Professional Institute)](http://www.lpi.org/)

There's also the wide selection of Linux User Groups (LUGs); there's a full list [here](http://www.linux.org/groups/), although they're not as "professional" as some of the other entries listed here.

Answer (score 0):

[NPA (Network Professional Association)](http://www.npanet.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Linux Australia is worth mentioning as they run linux.conf.au which has a large sysadmin component to it.

Similar groups do exist in other places, but often not to the same extent with running events.