# Sysadmin meet-ups and groups in Vancouver?

Tags: untagged

I'm going to be visiting Vancouver next month, and am wondering if anyone knows of any sysadmin related meet-ups that happen there on a regular basis? My partner and I have a plan to move there one day, so it would be good to get an idea of the industry and meet some tech folk there while I'm there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also the [VHS - Vancouver Hacker Space](http://vancouver.hackspace.ca/).

Comment: Seems like the domain has been left to go bad, but via http://hackerspaces.org/wiki/VHS it seems like there's activity on the IRC channel at irc.freenode.net #vhs

Comment: oops - my bad - https://vancouver.hackspace.ca is alive and well.

Comment: looks interesting btw, will try to pop in there on the tuesday open day!

Comment: The VHS is definitely a place to check out if you want to find interesting tech folks in Vancouver. The group has a strong systems and electronics bent, and is a great place to hang out.

Answer (score 1):

I've started a [list of sysadmin groups](https://serverfault.com/questions/20356/professional-groups-and-associations) which will provide a starting point for searching.  If you find any group not listed please add it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Vancouver Technology User Group](http://www.vantug.com/) is one. Microsoft and AMD have a Tech Tour once or twice a year (less often since the recession). Intel used to do Technical Solutions Training classes too, but those have also disappeared with the recession. Once things improve I expect they'll start up again.

Answer (score 1):

VTUG (http://www.vantug.com/), in which I am the member even though I never attended a single meeting. The leader, Graham Jones, of the user group is a very enthusiasm guy who did a pretty good job organizing the group and getting it going and growing steadily. One thing I don't like that group though, is that it somehow keen too much on the physical meeting rather than a meeting on the place like serverfault. They really should do more work on this as I am sure there are just much more people like me who don't have time to attend those meeting but are very much willing contribute to the community, in a much virtual way. :)

Hope it helps.

Side note, Vancouver is such a beautiful place for living. If you are still considering the idea of moving, you should at least pay the visit here in Summer because it's the best season in the year, and it lasts for at least 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

In a different forum, [Tazzu](http://www.tazzu.com) has been recommended to me as a good general technology/entrepreneur group.

Also, via the VHS webpage, [VanCAL](http://vancal.org/) seems a young but useful tech events listing.